# webcam access in c++

Tags: c++, windows, webcam

I want to access the webcam so I can do some precessing on the images, like tracking a light, but I can't find a way to access the webcam. I googled it but I got confused.

Can you point me to a library that can do that (windows)? and maybe also provide an example?

I would need to periodically get a pixel map of the image, about 20 time per second or so if it would be possible.

Comment: Please update this post. Is there a updated version or another development platform suited for WIndows 10.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkout [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/releases/). It is a cross-platform computer vision SDK and has modules to capture images from the webcam. Maybe too feature rich for you, but it's worth a look.

Answer (score 18):

You need [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454.aspx). This is a Windows framework for video playback and capture.

It's included in [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF) and there are many samples for video input capture included.

But, as Vijay mentioned, you can also try using [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary) since it not only abstracts away the platform-specific video capture API, it also includes many image processing algorithms you could use to track the light in your project.

Answer (score 14):

There's a wrapper for DirectMedia/DirectShow called [Extremely Simple Capture API](http://sol.gfxile.net/escapi/index.html) or ESCAPI. If you don't need to do anything complicated, ESCAPI might be a good bet.

Comment: this lib is awesome easy to use!

Comment: I'd like to add a note that I just used ESCAPI for a project that demanded video capture and for which I wanted to use GLUT (rather than ten pages of Windows calls) and I've been thrilled with it.

Comment: I've tried using it but it didn't work. Apparently my webcam used MJPG encoding at it only supports uncompressed encodings.

Answer (score 5):

If you target Windows Vista (or Seven), there's the new Media Foundation SDK, which is slightly easier to manipulate and more feature-rich, and most important, will be better supported by Microsoft in the future.

You can find out about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694197(VS.85).aspx).

And about video capture specifically [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317910(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

you can try openframeworks as well http://openframeworks.cc/

Answer (score 2):

You can use DirectShow:
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms783323(VS.85).aspx)