# Windows + Qt and how to capture webcam feed without OpenCV

Tags: windows, qt, webcam

I'm fighting with this problem from a long time.
I can't get OpenCV to work, and I have follow a lot of tutorials about it and how to use in Qt, so I get tired and I want to avoid the use of OpenCV for this.

Now, my requirement or question... I need to show a webcam feed (real time video, without audio) in a Qt GUI application with only one button: "Take Snapshot" which, obviusly, take a picture from the current feed and store it.

That's all.

Is there anyway to get this done without using OpenCV ?

System specification:

- Qt 4.8
- Windows XP 32 bits
- USB 2.0.1.3M UVC WebCam (the one I'm using now, it should support other models too)

Hope anybody can help me with this because I'm getting crazy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a few options listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259192/webcam-access-in-c but the `DirectShow` API is probably what'll work best.

Comment: Cr*p... I search and search so I don't duplicate a question, and there it was... Thanks Nicholas

Comment: Well, I read about DirectShow on the question you point, it appears to be easy or almost compatible with my needs, the thing is that I can't found any complete example about how to interact with DirectShow from Qt. I'm doing some research now, but if someone want to help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You interact with it much the same way you would with any library, make sure the compiler has the headers and you're linking against it.

Comment: Yes, I'm just reading about it... the problem becomes when I want to fill a QLabel with the video source, the webcam. The weird part is that I can't found any example about it, so I'm a bit nervous if maybe it's more hard than I thought.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much, you can fill a QLabel with a video source pretty easily (although there's dedicated video widgets inside Qt so have a look at the QMultimedia libs) and whilst Microsoft has a tendency to do some fugly things with macro deffed variables you can still extract the data out and get it into the QLabel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I finally did it, so I will post here my solution so we have something clear about this.

I used a library called 'ESCAPI': http://sol.gfxile.net/escapi/index.html

This provide a extremely easy way to capture frames from the device. With this raw data, I just create a QImage which later show in a QLabel.

I created a simple object to handle this.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "camera.h"

Camera::Camera(int width, int height, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    width_(width),
    height_(height)
{
    capture_.mWidth = width;
    capture_.mHeight = height;
    capture_.mTargetBuf = new int[width * height];

    int devices = setupESCAPI();
    if (devices == 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "[Camera] ESCAPI initialization failure or no devices found";
    }
}

Camera::~Camera()
{
    deinitCapture(0);
}

int Camera::initialize()
{
    if (initCapture(0, &capture_) == 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "[Camera] Capture failed - device may already be in use";
        return -2;
    }
    return 0;
}

void Camera::deinitialize()
{
    deinitCapture(0);
}

int Camera::capture()
{
    doCapture(0);
    while(isCaptureDone(0) == 0);

    image_ = QImage(width_, height_, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    for(int y(0); y < height_; ++y)
    {
        for(int x(0); x < width_; ++x)
        {
            int index(y * width_ + x);
            image_.setPixel(x, y, capture_.mTargetBuf[index]);
         }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And the header file:

```
#ifndef CAMERA_H
#define CAMERA_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include "escapi.h"

class Camera : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Camera(int width, int height, QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Camera();
    int initialize();
    void deinitialize();
    int capture();
    const QImage& getImage() const { return image_; }
    const int* getImageRaw() const { return capture_.mTargetBuf; }

private:
    int width_;
    int height_;
    struct SimpleCapParams capture_;
    QImage image_;
};

#endif // CAMERA_H
```

It's so simple, but just for example purposes.
The use should be something like:

```
Camera cam(320, 240);
cam.initialize();
cam.capture();
QImage img(cam.getImage());
ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

Of course, you can use a QTimer and update the frame in QLabel and you will have video there...

Hope it help! and thanks Nicholas for your help!

Comment: I forget to mention that you need to put the lib escapi.dll in the same directory of your app and, of course, add escapi.cpp and escapi.h to your compile command.

Comment: Oh wow- this is wonderful! Easier to follow than my Actionscript3 version. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I got " [Camera] ESCAPI initialization failure or no devices found" .i have cam on my lap