# Webcam - Windows based sdk

Tags: winapi, webcam, video-capture

I have read this question here: [webcam access in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259192/webcam-access-in-c)
however just wondering if there is any updated answers since 2009:

I would like to plug in a Webcam to a windows based system, and have a software that monitors and processes in real-time the webcam feed (eg. scan a barcode). I'm wondering what are some solutions out there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video capture APIs are still the same:

- [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Video for Windows (deprecated)

and then a multitude of wrappers over the mentioned, esp. over DirectShow and VfW.

You want to initialize video capture session with a camera, capture video and process it, e.g. to detect bar codes fro the incoming video feed.